# Common table expression (CTE) in table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am used to using common table expressions (CTEs) with MSSQL 2008 R2.  I know that the grammar is a bit fiddly about where they can appear, and that in ordinary T-SQL an explicit semicolon (or starting a new batch) is needed before a `with` expression.  I would like to use CTEs in a user-defined function.  For simple cases, this works:

```
create function dbo.udf_test()
returns table
with schemabinding
as
return (
  with foo as (
    select 5 as f
  )
  select f
  from foo
)
```

But now I would like to make my function `udf_test` a bit more elaborate.  For example to declare a variable inside the body of the function.  To start with I need to have explicit `begin` and `end` since the function body will no longer be a single statement.  So I try to create one thus:

```
create function dbo.udf_test()
returns table
with schemabinding
as
begin
  return (
    with foo as (
      select 5 as f
    )
    select f
    from foo
  )
end
```

However this gives the error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
```

How can I use a CTE in my table-valued function if it is more complex than a single `return` statement?

Comment: If you add more than 1 statement to your inline table valued function it will not longer be an inline table valued function. It will become a multi-statement table valued function. As such, the performance is going to tank horrifically. Often these are even worse than scalar functions. BTW, you do not need to wrap your return in parenthesis like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  In this particular case the function is not embedded in any larger query, but is called directly and the results inserted directly into another table.  So I am not concerned about whether the optimizer can 'see through' the function definition by inlining it.  Still I will keep an eye out for slowdowns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_test()
RETURNS 
@return TABLE 
(
    f int NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    WITH foo AS (
        SELECT 5 AS f
    )
    INSERT INTO @return
    SELECT f
    FROM foo;

    RETURN;
END
```